# I don't have write permission in the AppData folder

Tags: windows, visual-studio, access-denied, appdata

I'm getting separate errors when opening and closing Visual Studio. These errors occurred after making the AppData folder visible from hidden status."

Screenshot:
[image: when closing visual studio]

I tried to set the permissions from AppData, but the permissions were full and my problem was not solved.

Comment: There are other things besides NTFS permissions that cause errors like this; for example, consider the concept of [exclusive-locks on files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfile)...